# WebRTC Audio Session iOS in Background Mode

Tags: ios, webrtc, xcode9, callkit, pushkit

I am using WebRTC in iOS for Making Video Call.In earlier Xcode/iOS Versions, Audio & Voice over IP in Background Mode. It was working fine in background mode.

Now, I saw Voice over IP is missing in Xcode 9 & Call is disconnecting in the background.

It gives option

"Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9"

after certain seconds (50 seconds).

Any guideline?

Comment: This is one error that has troubled me a lot and is associated with background fetch. Few answers on SO also says that, it could be because of memory spike etc. Have you done profiling? I'm not sure on the answer though.

Comment: I didn't do any profiling so far. I am more curious about Call Kit and Push Kit here.

Comment: Try doing a quick memory allocation profiling? You can quickly see that in Xcode's `Show the Debug Navigator`

Comment: I am doing it now, yet I am more certain about CallKit, must be used here. as No Option on VoIP in Xcode at all.

Comment: Hi @ChatarVeerSuthar I'm also now working on video call app using WebRTC. I did it and working fine on foreground. I don't know how to handle it in the background. please help.

Comment: For me it wasn't related to background issue but another termination of call event which was triggered if user in background for longer than 50 seconds. 

For you, can you explain problem exactly so can try to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can add support doing manually

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
    <string>voip</string>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

Well some notes are as below.

- WebRTC - Newer works when app is in background or terminated mode
- You can debug your code while app is in terminated mode, so you can exactly figure our the reason of crash

You can refer related material here

https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification